# How to return false if the number is not found in the list

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

So, I am trying to do this hw problem: write a function that takes two arguments, a list and a number, and the function returns the index of the leftmost occurrence of the number in the list. For example:

- If `'(1 2 3 3 4)` and `num = 3`, then it returns `2`
- If `'(3 2 3 3 4)` and `num = 3`, then it returns `0`

I was able to do that part but what if the number was never found? What if I want to return false when `num` is not found in the list? How do I do that?

Please remember, I am trying to do this in proper recursion, not tail recursion.

Here's my code.

```
(define (first_elt_occ lst num)
   (cond
       ((null? lst) #f)
       ((eq? (car lst) num) 0)
       (else
          (+ 1 (first_elt_occ (cdr lst) num)))))

(first_elt_occ '(1 2 3 3 4) 3) ;2
(first_elt_occ '(3 2 3 3 4) 3) ;0
(first_elt_occ '(1 2 5 4 3) 3) ;4
(first_elt_occ '(1 2 5 4 3) 6) ;Error 
     ;(makes sense because you can't add boolean expression)
```

Another question I have is, how would I approach this problem, if I was asked to return the index of the *rightmost* occurrence of the number in a list (proper recursion). For example: `'(3 4 5 4 3 7 )`, `num = 3` returns `4`.

Thank you!

Comment: Trivial to do with tail recursion (And more efficient)....

Comment: greatly asked! :)

Comment: You have two different questions in the same post, let's address the first one in here and please post a second question once you've found a satisfactory answer for the first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this will be easier if we implement the procedure using tail recursion - by the way, tail recursion *is* "proper recursion", what makes you think otherwise?

By defining a helper procedure called `loop` and passing the accumulated result in a parameter, we can return either `#f` or the index of the element:

```
(define (first_elt_occ lst num)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (acc 0))
    (cond
      ((null? lst) #f)
      ((equal? (car lst) num) acc)
      (else (loop (cdr lst) (add1 acc))))))
```

If, for some bizarre requirement you can't use tail recursion in your solution, it's possible to rewrite you original solution to account for the case when the answer is `#f` - but this isn't as elegant or efficient:

```
(define (first_elt_occ lst num)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) #f)
    ((equal? (car lst) num) 0)
    (else
     (let ((result (first_elt_occ (cdr lst) num)))
       (if (not result) #f (add1 result))))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(first_elt_occ '(1 2 3 3 4) 3) ; 2
(first_elt_occ '(3 2 3 3 4) 3) ; 0
(first_elt_occ '(1 2 5 4 3) 3) ; 4
(first_elt_occ '(1 2 5 4 3) 6) ; #f
```

Comment: Thank you. My professor wants us to implement the problem using tail recursion and "proper recursion" - stack grows and shrinks. I already knew how to implement it in tail recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend actually taking this approach because a normal tail-recursive implementation is a lot more efficient, simpler, and easier to understand, but you can use a continuation to short-circuit unwinding the call stack in the failure case:

```
(define (first_elt_occ lst num)
  (call/cc
   (lambda (return)
     (letrec ((loop (lambda (lst)
                      (cond
                       ((null? lst) (return #f))
                       ((= (car lst) num) 0)
                       (else (+ 1 (loop (cdr lst))))))))
        (loop lst)))))
```

Comment: Thank you. My professor wants us to implement the problem using tail recursion and "proper recursion" - stack grows and shrinks. I already knew how to implement it in tail recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The basic *find first occurrence* ["skeleton" function](https://www.google.com/search?q=skeleton%20function%20art%20of%20prolog) is

```
(define (first_elt_occ lst num)
   (and (not (null? lst))
        (or (equal (car lst) num)
            (first_elt_occ (cdr lst) num))))
```

This does *not* return index though. How to add it in?

```
(define (first_elt_occ lst num)
   (and (not (null? lst))
        (or (and (equal (car lst) num) 0)
            (+ 1 (first_elt_occ (cdr lst) num)))))
```

Does it work? Not if the element isn't there! It'll cause an error then. How to fix that? Change the `+`, that's how!

```
(define (first_elt_occ lst num)
  (let ((+ (lambda (a b) (if b (+ a b) b))))
    (and (not (null? lst))
         (or (and (= (car lst) num) 0)
             (+ 1 (first_elt_occ (cdr lst) num))))))
```

And now it works as expected:

```
> (first_elt_occ '(1 2 3 3 4) 3)
2
> (first_elt_occ '(3 2 3 3 4) 3)
0
> (first_elt_occ '(3 2 3 3 4) 5)
#f
```

And to get your second desired function, we restructure it a little bit, into

```
(define (first_elt_occ lst num)
  (let ((+ (lambda (a b) ...... )))
    (and (not (null? lst))
         (+ (and (= (car lst) num) 0)
            (first_elt_occ (cdr lst) num)))))
```

Now, what should that new `+` be? Can you finish this up? It's straightforward!

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you are opposed to tail recursion. You talk about "proper recursion", which is not a technical term anyone uses, but I assume you mean non-tail recursion: a recursive process rather than an iterative one, in SICP terms. Rest assured that tail recursion is quite proper, and in general is preferable to non-tail recursion, provided one does not have to make other tradeoffs to enable tail recursion.

As Óscar López says, this problem really is *easier* to solve with tail recursion. But if you insist, it is certainly possible to solve it the hard way. You have to avoid blindly adding 1 to the result: instead, inspect it, adding 1 to it if it's a number, or returning it unchanged if it's false. For example, see the `number?` predicate.